# AZURE SQL login failed

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I'm having some issues with logging in to my azure sql server. The problem is that I do not know the server level principal, and the database has never been logged into before. Is there a way to connect to the database for the first time without server level principal? Is it possible to change server level principal password from portal?

Comment: Azure SQL also prevents logins if the firewall rules are not configured properly. You can refer [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/sql-database-configure-firewall-settings/) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you can change the server password from the portal on your server options :

[image]

Comment: I have tried to change it, but i still cant log in with admin username and new password...

Comment: Did you actually check the firewall rules link I gave? Also note that many company proxies might block 1433 port.